# jQuery placeholders substitution

Tags: jquery, regex, filter, match, placeholder

Let's say I have two placeholders in my HTML:

```
[$[SKU001]$]
[$[SKU002]$]
```

and I would like to 1) obtain SKU001 and SKU002 and put them in an array to be submitted by ajax to an api 2) to substitute both placeholders with, lets's say, an image tag obtained by api response:

```
<img src="SKU001.jpg">
<img src="SKU002.jpg">
```

I would like to achieve this using jQuery and its filter/match method.
Is it possible?

I'm trying to print this out:

```
var pattern = /\[\$\[(.*?)\]\$\]/;
var t = $('body').filter(function() {
    return this.??.match(pattern);
});

console.log(t);
```

but I'm not able to obtain the searched parameter in my pattern.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method doesn't work that way. It's for filtering DOM elements, not page content.

What you want to do is probably more in the direction of:

```
var matches = $('body').text().match(/\[\$\[(.*?)\]\$\]/)
console.log(matches);
```

Comment: That's good! Adding a "/g" at the end of pattern it is able to search globally too. But how to achieve the "SKU001", "SKU002" array? Using actual pattern it produces ["[$[SKU001]$]","[$[SKU002]$]"] only.

Comment: It's a trade-off that you will only get the entire match when using the `g` flag with JS's RegEx. If the bits of text will always have `[$[` and `]$]` at the beginning and end, you could use `String.slice(3, -3)` on each result to trim those bits off and get the part in the middle. [jQuery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) may come in handy for that.